# How does worker process bind itself to a single CPU?

Tags: webserver, nginx

In nginx config suppose I set the worker processes count to 4

Assuming the machine has got 4 CPU's, how does each nginx worker process bind itself to a single CPU?

Answer (score 2):

Limiting a process or thread to specific CPUs is typically called "CPU affinity".

Nginx uses [sched_setaffinity()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setaffinity.2.html) on Linux, [cpuset_setaffinity()](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=cpuset_setaffinity&sektion=2&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD+7.2-RELEASE) on FreeBSD. See [source](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/src/os/unix/ngx_setaffinity.c).

(On Windows it could use [SetProcessAffinityMask()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setprocessaffinitymask), but for some reason doesn't.)

Explicitly setting CPU affinity for worker processes isn't always required; Nginx probably gains some performance by doing so, but even if it did not, the OS scheduler would still automatically distribute load across CPUs more or less evenly (e.g. if you had 4 busy processes, they'd still run 1 per core most of the time).